# CSS "overflow: hidden;" still works on the pseudo "::after"

Tags: css, overflow, pseudo-element

`content: '>';` in `::after` is clipped by `overflow: hidden;`

```css
.centered-text {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 30vw;
}

.centered-text::before {
  content: '<';
}

.centered-text::after {
  content: '>';
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <span style="float:left;">I'm on the left</span>
  <span class="centered-text">a brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</span>
  <span style="float:right;">I'm on the right</span>
</div>
```

Result:

```
I'm on the left         <a brown fox jumps over th...          I'm on the right
```

The `'>'` in `::after` is clipped.

What I expected is '>' is still visible.

```
I'm on the left         <a brown fox jumps over th...>         I'm on the right
```

I had added `overflow: visible;` into `::after` to override that in `.centered-text` but '>' was still clipped.

Answer (score 0):

`.centered-text::after` is considered a child of `.centered-text`, which means it will be treated as a normal, actual child element when it comes to `overflow: hidden`.

A solution is to wrap the text inside another element and apply styles to that instead:

```html
<div>
  <span>...</span>
  <span class="centered-text">
    <span>a brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</span>
  </span>
  <span>...</span>
</div>
```

```css
.centered-text span {
  /* ... */
}
```

Try it:

```css
.centered-text span {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 30vw;
}

.centered-text::before {
  content: '<';
}

.centered-text::after {
  content: '>';
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <span style="float:left;">I'm on the left</span>
  <span class="centered-text">
    <span>a brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</span>
  </span>
  <span style="float:right;">I'm on the right</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css variable and use position absolute and set the css variable via javascript.

```js
const centeredText = document.getElementsByClassName('centered-text')[0]
const rect = centeredText.getBoundingClientRect()
document.documentElement.setAttribute("style", "--right-arrow-width: "+ rect.right+"px");
```

```css
:root {
  --right-arrow-width: 0px;
}
.centered-text {

    box-sizing: content-box;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 30vw;
}
.centered-text::before {
    content: '<';
}
.centered-text::after {
      content: '>';
      left: var(--right-arrow-width);
      position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <span style="float:left;">I'm on the left</span>
        <span class="centered-text">a brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</span>
        <span style="float:right;">I'm on the right</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

@InSync Thank you! The problem of additional  wrapper is
[lots of spaces and disalignment of '<>'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFPuy.jpg) if I shorten the message to `<span>a brown fox</span>`